# cmake: "cxx11" is not a recognized standard

Tags: mysql, macos, cmake, homebrew, macos-catalina

While setting up mysql@5.6 on macOS Catalina I've encountered this error

% brew install mysql@5.6
Error: cmake: "cxx11" is not a recognized standard

Any help would be great.

Edit: I've tried the below solution as mentioned on https://github.com/caskformula/homebrew-caskformula/issues/90

brew cask reinstall xquartz

brew cask uninstall inkscape

brew cleanup

brew cask install inkscape

This did not help

Comment: I am not a Mac user, so I really don't have any idea, but I would imagine seeing that error if you have either a really old version of Cmake or a really old compiler that doesn't support C++11. I would perhaps try upgrading cmake first

Comment: run 3 commands $ brew untap caskformula/caskformula
$ brew doctor $brew upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Seem failed to install from bottle (pre-built package). `cmake` is only needed if you're building the package from source code.

Update Homebrew and try again.

```sh
brew update
brew install homebrew/core/mysql@5.6
```